# Non-convex quadratic optimization

Tags: non-convex-optimization

I would like to optimize the following system:
$$\min_{q,\|q\|=1} \sum_i^n |q^T M_i q|$$

More details:

- the size of the unknown vector $q$ is $4 \times 1$,
- $M_i$ is a matrix of size $4\times 4$. It is symmetric but *not* positive definite,
- $n$ is about $200$ in my case.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

It might be related to the following problem:
$$\max_{q,\|q\|=1} q^T M q$$
The solution is simply the eigenvector of $M$ associated to the highest eigenvalue.

But in our system, the absolute function and the sum make the problem more complicated.

I also tried reformulating the system as:
$$\min_{q,t} \sum_i^n t_i \text{ subject to }|q^T M_i q|\leq t_i\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,n\text{ and }\|q\|=1$$
but it did not really help.

It is not a standard quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP) because the matrices are not positive definite.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Is there a chance the $M_{i}$s are copositive?

Comment: I suspect that a good nonlinear programming solver would give you an accurate (floating-point) solution fairly quickly (for instance, try MATLAB's fmincon).  This ignores all the structure of the problem, but it will probably work.

Comment: It is not a QCQP because the objective is linear. Positive definiteness has to do with the QCQP's convexity (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach which may get you good results but for which I have no guarantees.

Letting $Q = qq^T$ you can rewrite your constraints as $-t_i \leq \text{Trace}(M_iQ)\leq t_i$.  Requiring $Q$ to factor as $qq^T$ for some $q$ of unit norm is the same as saying that $Q$ is positive semidefinite, has unit trace, and rank one.  Dropping the rank one constraint gives a semidefinite programming relaxation and hence an efficiently computable lower bound to the objective value.

If you're lucky, the optimal $Q$ may be rank one, in which case you have the optimal solution to the original problem.  If not, the eigendecomposition of the optimal $Q$ may suggest decent candidate solutions yielding objective values close to this bound.